# R system call returning stdin without escape characters

Tags: python, r, system

EDIT: This question was poorly thought out. My issue is actually with simply trying to display the text via shiny - not storing it. Somedays you just don't think clearly.

I have a python script that prints some results to stdin that I would like to read into a character vector in R. This generally works great using `system(...,intern=TRUE)`, however in this case it does not work for me when escape characters are added on (the script returns HTML and adding escape characters can lead to malformed HTML). I can get around this by saving the output from python into a temporary file and reading that file into R, but I'd rather avoid that if there is an easy fix that I can't think of. Here is an example of what I mean:

```
> #f.py is a text file containing
>
> # #!/usr/bin/python
> # 
> # html = """
> #     <HTML>
> #             <p>some content</p>
> #             <p> some more content </p>
> #         </HTML>"""
> # 
> # print html
> 
> #the /t, among other escapes, break the html
> v1 <- paste(system("./f.py",intern=TRUE),collapse="")
> v1
[1] "\t\t<HTML>\t\t\t<p>some content</p>\t\t  \t<p> some more content </p>\t\t</HTML>"
> 
> #this is what I want... but it needs to be saved into an object
> system("./f.py")

        <HTML>
            <p>some content</p>
            <p> some more content </p>
        </HTML>
> #or equivalently
> cat(v1)
        <HTML>          <p>some content</p>         <p> some more content </p>      </HTML>
> 
> #I thought capture.output() would work, but the string still has the escaped characters
> v2 <- capture.output(cat(v1))
> v2
[1] "\t\t<HTML>\t\t\t<p>some content</p>\t\t  \t<p> some more content </p>\t\t</HTML>"
```

Comment: Where is `paste()` imported from (or is it your own function?)

Comment: paste is just base R (base::paste) - it's only to each line into a single character vector (without it you would get a vector of length 4 split by line breaks)

Comment: I was reading this as a question about using R in Python not the other way around.  My bad :)

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. Please let me know if you think it's confusing to read and I will do my best to remove the ambiguity.

Comment: The ambiguity was all on my side.  There is a Python command called `system()` (`from os import system` would let you invoke it like that though commonly it is invoked like `os.system()`) that does the same thing (though with different arguments) and a module called `paste` though with no functionality like `R`'s paste.  Your first sentence is clear.  I don't know `R` but could it be representing tab characters as `\t` and not actually populating the string with `\\` and \`t\`?

Comment: My guess is that you're just confused about how R is storing the data versus how it is displaying it.  When you use paste R will show a tab as \t and what not - but that's just because it's showing you what it has stored.  If you use something like `cat` instead you'll see the actual representation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is working fine, R is just printing your escaped characters as escapes. If you do

```
cat(paste(system("./f.py", intern=TRUE), collapse=""))
```

you should see your desired output.

Comment: Sorry I spoke too soon. That does not actually work for my purposes. I need to store a literal character string that reads what is printed when when `cat()` is applied to the result.

Comment: You mean instead of "\t", you want to see "        " (8 spaces), but without using `cat`? That's pretty weird. Can you provide more background?

Comment: I edit the original post, but I was basically just having a dumb day. My issue clearly isn't with storing the data it's pumping it through a shiny interface to display correctly. I"ll just accept your answer since my question doesn't really make sense.